Using a regression model, is it possible to precisely predict "outlier" results based on a highly imbalanced dataset?
Title.
I have a dataset that's highly imbalanced, say the output variable I want to predict is restricted within the range from 0 to 1, but almost all of the datapoints sit around 0.7-0.9, while my prediction set is mostly values from 0 to 0.4.
I see there is a huge gap. So far, my prediction is completely off. I believed it is caused by imbalanced dataset, but due to the nature of my data, I can't add any more points. I tried some data augmentation strats but did not work very well. I am also aware of oversampling methods like ADASYN and SMOTE, but since my dataset are purely numerical, those methods are not applicable.
Is there any way to deal with this dilemma, or I have to admit that due to the distribution of my dataset, such regression issue is unsolvable?

update 2024-06-07
I am using Random Forest from Scikit-learn package. I did try some benchmark models like linear regression, but the result is even worse (x-reality, y-prediction): 
below is my prediction vs reality result using random forest, as you can see, most of the predictions is far from correct. R2 is less than 0, RMSE is about 0.5.

"When you refer to the prediction set, do you mean that your predictions are between 0 and 0.4 or that the true values are between 0 and 0.4?"
I meants the true values are between 0 and 0.4.


$1)$ What techniques have you used to make the predictions? $//$ $2)$ Have you plotted the predicted and true values? What does that plot look like? It will be helpful to plot a $y=x$ line in that graph, as that is the ideal relationship. $//$ $3)$ How does your performance compare to that of simple benchmarks like linear regression or even just predicting the mean every time, regardless of feature values? (This relates to the Gneiting-Resin $R^*$ I have posted about a few times, if not here then at least on Cross Validated.)

@MuhammedYunus The trouble is that the model seems to think there is a high probability of being less than 0.4. Something has gone wrong to get predictions that (I assume) severely underperform a simple benchmark like always predicting the mean. $//$ Another question: are the bad predictions in-sample or out-of-sample?

@Dave Yes I think you're right. I read "prediction set" differently initially, but it probably just means "predictions".

@Yuuya When you refer to the prediction set, do you mean that your predictions are between 0 and 0.4 or that the true values are between 0 and 0.4?

@Dave Hi Dave, just updated my post with more details, feel free to take a look.

@Yuuya You have a totally different test set than training set. Of course your predictions are terrible when you pull out the rug from under the model. Why are the true values in the test set so markedly different from those in the training set? If you are using one time period to make predictions about a future time period (not at all an unreasonable task to want to accomplish), then you are not accounting for something that changes between the two time periods (a new President or Prime Minister came into office, for example).

my dataset is experiment data where the features are the setting of the experiment and the output variable is a measuring metric. the mechanics of the experiment is still unclear, so we want to use the current data to predict the result of the experiments that we have not done yet. ideally we want that result metric to be as high as possible(max=1), as a result along with the fact that experimenter tends to aim for the highest result possible, they tend to reuse the good conditions that have been proved to produce good results, so most datapoints in my dataset have a high output value.

But why should your test data be so dramatically different? It is as if you have trained on monkeys and are testing on humans. Is there any kind of known operational condition that differs between the two groups? One group is men and the other women? One group is monkeys and the other humans? One group is the UK and the other France?

yeah i see the conflict.... all data comes from a family of chemical reactions such that A+B+C+D=E, where ABCD are 4 different factors from 4 different molecules, from which i extract chemical props as final features. the train data are published and test data are unpublished so we can claim we "predict" the unknown results that can be proved by experiments. however, the test data was not published because the result/output variable is quite low and not that excicting judgding from a chemist and that's where i am right now, holding mostly high data points and trying to predict low data points.

Perhaps this isn’t the final answer, but how are your predictions if you mix together both the published and unpublished reactions? That is, combine everything into one set from which you allocate a mix of published and unpublished reactions to the training data.

yeah, i tried to mix them and made a k-fold out of the whole dataset and the performance was quite nice, but since mixing unpublished with published is against the idea of the research, it's not quite helpful....

on the other side, is there any specific model that can allieviate the effect of the imbalanced dataset?

Why does mixing the published and unpublished reactions go against the spirit of the research? You can make good predictions about how the reactions will proceed, whether they are publishable result or not, can’t you? $//$ If you don’t want to mix the two sets, then you have a major issue of data drift, and I stand by my earlier comment that of course your model performs poorly when you pull out the rug from under the model. $//$ I do not see any issues with imbalance. Your issue is data drift.

I see your point, I tried to convince my team manager with similar idea but he insisted we must predict the unpublished results to make the project worth a paper since it's "meaningless" to predict something that we already know, i.e., the published results......

But it does predict the unpublished results… $//$ As Harrell says around 53:00, you need to argue for correct methodology. (Frank Harrell is kind of a legendary biostatistician, if you are not familiar with his work.)

It does predict, but it's not accurate, even completely unreliable sometimes, which goes against the idea of prediction as we always want accurate prediction.... Harrell made a great point there. Good mind. Now say if there is no way to further improve the performance of any model based on this dataset, would you say i should rather stop this project, given that the published/unpublished split is probably unavoidable?

Not being able to make accurate predictions is a separate matter.

Your setup has you in a position where you’re trying to predict something you are not modeling. When you train on one group and then test on a considerably different group, of course the predictions are terrible when you have not trained to detect relationships for that group.
You need to model your group of interest. Since you performed the experiments to collect data for that group, you have the information available to make predictions about your group of interest. It also makes sense to include the current training group, as that gives the model more data and also puts you in a position be able to predict higher outcomes.
Your manager wanting to exclude the group of interest from the training has made a mistake with conditional probability. You go into a prediction problem not knowing what the outcome is, so your manager’s argument has an implicit conditioning on the unknown. That’s a problem when the whole point is to develop a system to make predictions about whether or not the results of a chemical reaction will be a high value or not. It is time to argue with the manager and win that argument.
